# How to change Chocolatey's install location?

Tags: powershell, chocolatey

I installed Rufus with Chocolatey and I couldn't find its install location.  After some research, I found that it installed to the hidden "Program Files" directory.  I could run it from PowerShell, but the normal Winkey+[appname] search won't work.  Is there a way to resolve this so that I can open apps I install in Chocolatey without having to open it from Powershell Admin?

Answer (score 0):

Note: I don't actually know how to complete what your asking in the text, So I'm just explaining what to do that you asked in the title.

There are 2 ways.

The first way is to create the enviroment value ChocolateyInstall before installing chocolatey and setting the value as where you want to install chocolatey

Step 1:
Search `Enviroment Variable` On the start menu.

Step 2:
Create an enviroment variable called `ChocolateyInstall`

Step 3:
Set the value of the variable to where you wanna install Chocolatey
(e.g. `C:\Directory\Chocolatey`)

And also there's the second way.

The second way is by creating a junction link.

Step 1:
Open Command Prompt as Administrator

Step 2:
Go to where chocolatey would install. (In your case I think it would be C:\Program Files)

```
C:\Directory> cd "C:\Program Files"
```

Step 3:
Create the junction link
To create the junction link you will run

```
mklink /d Chocolatey X:\Directory
```

In this case X:\Directory would be where you'd want to install Chocolatey.